# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading "small')

Tags: reactjs, api

in my react project I get api and store data in state.

```
const [infor,setInfor] = useState({}); //these is my hook for store data
const [chartdata,setChartdata] = useState([]);

useEffect(()=>{
    const setter = async()=>{
        const dd = await(info());
        setInfor(dd.data);
        console.log(dd.data);
        const dd2 = await(chart());
        setChartdata(dd2);
    }
    setter();
},[])
```

It works properly and store data very well. I store data in (infor)
I want to use that data in react component so write these code

```
    return (
    <div id={style.main}>
        {
        !infor ? <img src={spinner} /> : //these code checking infor isn't null
        <span className={style.info}>
            <img src={infor.image.small}  title={infor.id} className={style.icon} />
            <p>{infor.market_cap_rank}</p>
            <p>{infor.name}</p>

            
        </span>
        }
    </div>
);
```

these is data that I need[image]

everything seems well but this is an error
[image]

Comment: Your initial state is an empty object (`{}`), so until the data is loaded and `setInfor` is called, it doesn't contain the field `image.small` and that's why it throws an error. Try it like this: `<img src={infor.image?.small} ... />`

Comment: I checked this by {!infor ? <loader /> : <p>{.infor.imgae.small}</p>} -- first  Ichecked infor empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`!infor ? <img src={spinner} /> : /**/`

In above line `!infor` will always be true as `!{}` is true.
There are 2 ways to solve your problem.

1. initialize `infor` to `null`

   `const [infor,setInfor] = useState(null);`
2. Use [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to validate object

   `!Object.keys(infor).length ? <img src={spinner} /> : /***/`

Comment: thank you-it work // can you explain more ?

Comment: I am glad that I helped you. Please let me know what shall I explain more?

Answer (score 0):

In the first render when your compiler is searching for the infor.image, it is getting undefined, thus it is throwing an error. Either use put checks for the same like checking for infor exist, then image exists and then small exist. It can be done by using infor?.image?.small. But the problem with this is that you will get undefined on the screen. You have to put the checks correctly by keeping this in mind for example infor?.image?.small ? infor.image.small : ''.

Comment: Instead of writing the answer as a single statement, you could use necessary formatting. You can read more about it at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Thanks, Actually it was my first comment. Thanks for the pointers.